# local image upload not showing on Google App Engine

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Here is my upload function on server side:

```
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    // multipart request
    final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
    // some function to get the filename from part
    final String name = getFileName(filePart);
    // some function to convert the filename to GcsFilename
    final GcsFilename fileName = getFileNameGCS(name);
    //method to copy file taken from official documentation
    GcsFileOptions instance = GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance();
    GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, instance);
    copy(filePart.getInputStream(), Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));

}

private void copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
        try {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
          int bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
          while (bytesRead != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
          }
        } finally {
          input.close();
          output.close();
        }
    }
```

Here is my post function on client side (Angular2) album.component.ts:

```
  uploadAlbum(index:number){
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.targets[index].file, '/gcs/my-bucket/' + index +'/cover/cover.jpg');
    this.http.post('/api/photos',formData, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        console.log(data)
      },
       err => {
         console.log(err)
        }
      );
  }
```

now I use this method to retrieve the public url to my local file (App Engine Google Cloud Storage simulates a server upload and place it in a local space)

sample code:

```
...
BlobKey blobKey = blobStore.createGsBlobKey("/gs/" + bucket + "/" + listFilenames.get(i));
log.info("/gs/" + bucket + "/" + listFilenames.get(i));
ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
String url = imagesService.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey));
jsonObj.put("path", url);
json.put(jsonObj);
...
```

basically what I do in the other part of the function is parse through all the files and filter the one that I have interest in.

And it works I get the URL with the `encoded_gs_key` but nothing is showing at all.
Is there a problem with my upload? Do BlobStore serves a link even when it don't find a file at the specified location?
One more thing is that I always get the same `encoded_gs_key` link even though my folders and images are different (`0/cover/cover.jpg` and for example `1/cover/cover.jpg` so different root folders, different images but same filename)

Comment: How are you simulating the local Cloud Storage? And are you following a quickstart or a guide? Also, can you provide all parts of the code so that it's reproducible?

Comment: @TasosZG Thank you for your comment. I'm using this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage). I'm not simulating the local cloud storage it's appengine on dev mode that simulate an online upload by uploading to local space. Also most of the importnt code is here I could add the client side(html/js) though

Comment: Ok I'm trying out the tutorial and so far I can see that the `encoded_gs_key` is generated by the name of the complete path, which means that it will be generated regardless if the file exists or not. Also if you check again I assume that you get an **almost** identical `encoded_gs_key` for `0/cover/cover.jpg` and `1/cover/cover.jpg`, I checked and they were different by one character, which makes sense since it's generated by the name of the path. Can you confirm that it's not exactly identical?

Comment: Also you can get a view of the simulated (datastore) storage by going to `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin`. You can list the entities of each Kind and each Kind represents a "fake bucket". There's also one extra Kind which maps keys to `encoded_gs_keys`. Can you check if the images you upload are there?

Comment: many thanks for this comment nothing show I have a blank page when I go to your link. Any ideas why?

Comment: When I run `mvn appengine:devserver` to start the local development server it gives me "Module instance default is running at `http://localhost:8080/`" and "The admin console is running at `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin`". I'm running [this sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/tree/master/java/example) on the Cloud Shell.

Comment: @TasosZG let me restart my server I'm not using maven and using eclipse as ide. I added a connexion filter maybe that's why.

Comment: @TasosZG Hey many thanks you put me on the path. It was a filter error I'll answer my own question

Comment: Awesome! Glad that you resolved it!

Answer (score 1):

Now I understand what happened. I had a connection filter that letted me getting only through this path `/api*` I've deleted it and things seems to work better:

original connexionFilter class:

```
public class connexionFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();

        if(path.startsWith("/api"))
        {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```